# CSV File Reader Rows Return Incorrect Formatting

Tags: python, csv

When I run the reader of a csv file:

```
with open(filename, "r") as csvfile: 
  t_reader= csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter= ',')
  for row in t_reader: 
     return row
```

Now, row returns something like this:

```
['"a", "b", "c","d"']
```

Notice the single quotation marks, this makes the length of the list 1 instead of 4.
How do I make it so that the row returns something normal like:

```
["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

My csv file is structured like this:

[image: screenshot]

Now, when I run this through `t_reader` I get each row to be like:

```
['1,2,3,4,5']
```

Comment: Please, show the exact format of the csv file. Probably the file format is incorrect i.e. extra /excess quotes

Comment: I used Excel to create my csv list:

Comment: open the csv file in a program like Notepad or Notepad++ and copy a few lines, then edit your question to include the sample.

Comment: So, based on the image - this is wrong way to do it. you write in single excel cell and create a single field. You need to use different cell for each number and no comma to create proper csv file

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to do something like this on a mac?  Also, I'm trying to get a list for each t_reader row instead of one number.

Comment: Create proper csv file

Comment: In your example, cell A:1 is `1,2,3,4,5`. Look at the generated CSV file and you will see that quotes are used to let a CSV reader know that those commas are just part of a single cell, and not a cell separator. Python's CSV is working properly.

Answer (score -1):

Please create your Excel file as given in the attached picture and then export it to csv. This will create the csv in the correct way that your program expects.

Sample Excel:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: While this may solve the problem, it would be better to include some context, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it to make it more useful.